# Drupal 6 not saving

Tags: jquery, drupal

I am trying to fix a Drupal site which is built on Drupal 6.

It's custom content type with custom fields is not saving any changes including post title, fields etc.

I increased max_input_vars to 5000, updated jquery 1.2 to 1.5 etc, but still no luck.

Can anyone please advice me where to find and fix the issue please.

Thanks

Comment: Check the recent log messages for errors. Since this is a question of how to use Drupal not develop for Drupal you might do better on Drupal Answers: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Also Take Note: Drupal 6 is no longer officially supported by the community. While there are some places that are offering long term support for Drupal 6, you should plan to move to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related and better suited to: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/